# Question Regarding the Eigenvalues of Matrix Commutators

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

Let us consider a commutator of two diagonizable $n\times n$, i.e. square matrices, $A$ and $B$.  The eigenvalues of  $A$ are $\lambda^1,\lambda^2,...,\lambda^{n}$  The eigen values of $B$ are $\mu^1,\mu^2,...,\mu^{n}$ The (normalized) eigenvectors of $A$ are $\bf{a}^1,\bf{a}^2,...$ and of $B$ are $\bf{b}^1,\bf{b}^2,...$  We assume these eigenvalues and eigenvectors are all known, and eigenvalues of matrices may or may not have degenerecies.

The commutator we use here is
$$\sigma_{ab}=[A,B] =AB-BA$$
We will lable the eigenvalues of the commutator as $\sigma_{ab}^1,\sigma_{ab}^2,...$ and the eigenvectors as $\bf\sigma_{ab}$

We want a method to  calculate the eigenvalues and and associated eigenvectors of $\sigma_{ab}$   by computing directly from our known eigenvalues and eigenvectors of  $A$ and $B$ (to be clear *not* by using  $A$ and $B$ to compute $\sigma_{ab}$ and then its eigenvalues and eigenvectors)

Comment: There is no such method. The eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $[A, B]$ simply are not determined by the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$, and even worse, the eigenvalues of $[A, B]$ are not even bounded by any function of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The eigenvalues and a basis of associated eigenvectors determine the matrices $A$ and $B$ and thus also $[A,B]$. So in principle, the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $[A,B]$ are determined by the given data.

Comment: Right, let me rephrase. Certainly the eigenvalues alone are not determined by the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. As far as I know there is no way to do this that does not involve just directly computing $[A, B]$.